# Html.BeginForm does not redirect to action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-code

I try using Html.BeginForm to submit my data but it does not help me with it. I followed this link to make my mvc program: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f82e9a/form-data-submiting-and-displaying-data-another-view-using-m/

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitEmp","ClientController",FormMethod.Post))

using this I get the following error:

[image: i.e local host page can't be found.]

My view has a folder named Client, in which there are two files:

1. Index: this contains the form.
2. this the view to get the details entered in the previous form.
   My controller (ClientController) has the code mentioned in the link
   and my Model is Cmodel with the same code.

Comment: Remove the name 'Controller' use only 'Client' then it will work

Comment: Still in your URL `localhost:5000/ClientController/Submitemp` showing controller name ClientController it should be Client only change your URL like `localhost:5000/Client/Submitemp` then it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code should be like this then it will work

`@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitEmp","Client",FormMethod.Post))`

We cannot and use full controller name like ClientController for specifying controller name we need to specify only the name of Client

In your URL `localhost:5000/ClientController/Submitemp` showing controller name ClientController it should be Client only change your URL like `localhost:5000/Client/Submitemp` then it will work.

**Cheers!!**

Comment: The filename of my controller is "ClientController"

Comment: if your controller name like 'ClientControllerController' then you can specify ClientController other wise its just Client

Comment: ` public class ClientController: Controller   
    {  
        // GET: Home  
        public ActionResult Index()   
        {  
            Employee emp = new Employee();  
            return View(emp);  
        }  
  
        [HttpPost]  
        public ActionResult SubmitEmp(Employee emp)  
        {  
            TempData["Emp"] = emp;  
            return Redirect("/Client/EmpDetails");  
        }  
  
        public ActionResult EmpDetails()  
        {  
            Employee emp = TempData["Emp"] as Employee;  
            return View(emp);  
        }  `

Comment: Solved. Thanks :)

Comment: your controller name is  Client only its MVC standards that we can not include the name of controller like ClientController we just use Client

Comment: Thankyou, this helped.

Comment: But the thing is now the error has changed to "The page is not working"

Comment: check your return View(emp); emp view should include the layout page

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass "Controller" in controller name, simply pass "Client". Make sure you have "SubmitEmp" HttpPost action in Client Controller

Comment: My controller name is "ClientController".  and this my clientController:

        public ActionResult Index()   
        {  
            Employee emp = new Employee();  
            return View(emp);  
        }  
  
        [HttpPost]  
        public ActionResult SubmitEmp(Employee emp)  
        {  
            TempData["Emp"] = emp;  
            return Redirect("/Client/EmpDetails");  
        }  
  
        public ActionResult EmpDetails()  
        {  
            Employee emp = TempData["Emp"] as Employee;  
            return View(emp);  
        }

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have passed controller name as 'ClientController' which appears to be incorrect. The Controller in 'ClientController' represents that this is a Controller named Client. You can pass 'Client' instead of 'ClientController' in the place for controller.

Comment: The filename of my controller is "ClientController"

Comment: even if i write @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitEmp","Client",FormMethod.Post)) then also the same eroor continues